# How can I get the first item out of a session list in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-sessions

For example,

I set request.session['jump'] = [u'howhigh',u'justlow'] ( i did this by getting values from a form)

How can I get just the first value? I thought something like jump = request.session['jump'][0] would work, but its ont doing it for me.

Also how do i exclude the first value and return all but the one i excluded?

Comment: "It's not doing it for me" - well, what *is* it doing? What output it errors do you get? How/where are you using that code?

Comment: it outputs [U","U] - something along those lines. What i did to fix that was first set the session to a variable so blah = request.session['blah'] and then call blahh = blah[0]. I just didnt figure out the exclusion part, any clues? this is all done in the view

Comment: You need to show the actual view, then. And not "something along these lines": please show the *exact* output.